# Formal alternative to 'does not'

Tags: synonyms

I have been looking online for some good formal alternatives to 'does not' but I haven't found anything that seems ok.

It should fit in a sentence like this: "He doesn't have the ability to ...."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: He doesn't have the ability to fly -> He has no ability to fly -> He cannot fly

Comment: No worries. You may use *does not* in the most formal settings like court or contracts.

Comment: It's formal enough, but if you like, you can remove the negative as in "he lacks the ability".

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're looking for an alternative to the phrase "does not"? The phrase "does not" certainly sounds fine in formal writing, so I can't think of why you'd want an alternative. Are you asking for a completely general alternative for "does not" which will work in any context, or are you specifically asking for an alternative way to say "he does not have the ability to ..."?

Comment: Formal to the point of British stuffiness would be, "He has not the ability to fly."

Comment: British stuffiness about 150 years ago.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you think 'does not' is not formal? Or is it the contraction that is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

What could be more formal than *does not*?

There isn't another phrase that means the same thing. So I think you're there.

Answer (score 0):

> He lacks the ability to ...

Or maybe something like

> He does not appear to be qualified to ...